# Make user withdraw tokens

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, security

As a best -and most secure- practice, how do you make an user to withdraw tokens from your contract, without them having to initiate the withdrawal procedure (aka calling a withdraw function), instead of the contract sending them to the user?

Is this possible?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

```js
function withdrawTokens() external {
   //Do some logic
   //more logic

   IERC20(baseToken).transfer(msg.sender, inBalance); //<--- instead of this, a way for the user to get the tokens without initiating a transfer function
}
```

Comment: Without more information about your use case it will be hard to recommend an approach.  Here is a good article that may help point you in the right direction: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/universal-ethereum-delegated-transactions-no-more-ethereum-fees/

Comment: Thanks for the article but it wasn't what I'm looking for. It'd be something like the edit I added to the post @ruby_newbie

Comment: What you are describing sounds like 'Delegated transactions embedded directly into a (token) smart contract' from the article.  The user would sign(delegate authority to transfer tokens to you(the delegate)) and you would send them on their behalf.  They could/would sign up front and you can send when triggered by some other event.  Unless I am missing something.

Comment: It doesn't suit my case though. The user can't pre-authorize the transfer. @ruby_newbie

Comment: Who owns/controls the tokens in question?  If they belong to the user's account in the contract, no one else can transfer them on behalf of the user.  This is of course by design.  If the tokens are owned by the owner of the contract then the owner can issue the transfer to the recipient in question.

Comment: Yeah, they belong to the contract, not the user. @ruby_newbie